# Round up bytes to next nearest GB and return value in bytes

Tags: sql-server-2012

If I have `1023` bytes, how can I round this up to 1 GB and return `1024`, and similarly if I have, for example, `1900`, how can I round this up to `2048` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CEILING` and decimal arithmetic to round the value up to the higher 1024 multiple:

```
SELECT CEILING(1023/1024.0)*1024;
--1024
SELECT CEILING(1900/1024.0)*1024;
--2024
```